# Xamarin Forms - Lagging ScrollView after updating UI with HTTP POST Request Results

Tags: android, user-interface, http-post, scrollview, xamarin.forms

I'm working in the PCL with the last stable version of Xamarin Forms. For the moment, the targeted platform is Android.

First, I get the results from my HTTP POST request which is working perfectly fine.

Then, when I try to update the UI, the scrollview in which the results are displayed is lagging when I scroll down.

I think it might be a threading problem : the update of the UI may not be executed in the right thread.

I tried to use `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { //Update the UI });` but it is not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it lagging **while** you are updating and scrolling? Or is it lagging **after** the items got updated? Doesn't the scrolling lag before the update?

Comment: I reserved an empty stacklayout to display the results. I press a button, the items are correctly displayed and then when I try to scroll, it's lagging. So after.

Comment: The number of items can change based on the result of the request but in my example, I have 9 items to display.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some of my code to help us :

**Main Method:**

```
private async void Search() {   

   ResponseService results = await libSearch.getResults(this.searchEntry.Text); 

   if (results.error != true) {
       List<Choice> list = (List<Choice>)results.obj;

      if(list.Count != 0) { 

         foreach(Choice choice in list) {                                    

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
               addNewChoice(choice);                                   
            });

          }  

       }
   }
```

**AddNewChoice Method:**

```
private void addNewChoiceOnUI(Choice choice) {            

   ChoiceTemplate Choice = new ChoiceTemplate(choice.name, choice.img, choice.address);                           

   this.Choices.Children.Add(Choice);            
}
```

The **Web Service Call Method** seems to work. It looks like this :

```
 public async Task<ResponseService> getResults(string zipcode) {

 (...)

       JObject results = await JsonWebRequest.getDataFromService(queryString).ConfigureAwait(false);

 (...)
```

As you can see, I'm using an *await* on the web service call method and on the main method only. I'm also using `ConfigureAwait(false);` on the web service call method. I already tried numerous solutions. I would be so grateful if we could find a solution to avoid the lag.